# VB.NET to C# with Event Handlers

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, delegates, vb.net-to-c#

Hi all sorry but you must get this all the time, I have tried to search for it but could not find anything specific to what I am looking for.

Basically I pretty much know VB.NET fully and I use it constantly, something I want to get into is C# so I have decided to use my free time to try and get a grip on this. I am doing this by using one of my old VB.NET custom binary objects and converting it by hand (not really using a converter as I want to learn it rather than just converting it.) I am however using the internet to guide me. So far I am trying to create custom even handlers my previous VB.NET code was as follows;

```
Public Event BeforeExecution_Handler()
```

but doing it in C# seems to be a bit more trickier and i have made the following

```
public event BeforeExecution_HandlerEvent BeforeExecution_Handler;
public delegate void BeforeExecution_HandlerEvent();
```

No first is this correct, but secondly what is going on here, why do I have to create definitions for it twice. I am having a guess that the delegate section is where you put variables but why is it like this. Can somebody explain

Comment: `public event EventHandler BeforeExecution_Handler;`?

Comment: Hi yes I am aware of this, but I do not just want to convert it, I want to learn it. Hence why I have taken this approach otherwise I will be reliant on these tools never knowing what is actually needed. Again this question is relating to why I need both the event and delegate, am I missing something?

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: I've never declared an event in VB.NET like you did. Normally I declare them like: `Public Event MyEvent As EventHandler`. I guess when you remove the `As EventHandler` part the VB compiler automatically creates a delegate for you. However in C# that does not seem to be implemented, which is why you need to create it on your own. A `Delegate` is a pointer to a method, which is needed by the events so that they know for example which parameters are expected.

Answer (score 6):

In VB.NET you can *implicitly* create a delegate, so you can just do something like this:

Declaration:

```
Public Event MsgArrivedEvent(ByVal message As String) 'behind the scenes a delegate is created for you
```

Invocation:

```
RaiseEvent MsgArrived("foo")
```

In C# you **have** to use delegates.

Declaration:

```
public delegate void MsgArrivedEventHandler(string message);
public event MsgArrivedEventHandler MsgArrivedEvent;
```

Invocation:

```
MsgArrivedEvent("Test message");
```

---

Note that you can also *explicitly* create a delegate in VB.NET in the same way as C# but this is just more typing for no gain really:

Declaration:

```
Public Delegate Sub MsgArrivedEventHandler(ByVal message As String)
Public Event MsgArrivedEvent As MsgArrivedEventHandler
```

Invocation:

```
RaiseEvent MsgArrivedEvent("foo")
```

---

Also note that best practise is actually to use use a `sender` and `EventArgs` class (or a class inherited from it) as the parameters to the Event/Delegate:

```
public delegate void MsgArrivedEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

Comment: It´s also worth to mention that in most cases it is sufficient to use `EventHandler` or the generic version `EventHandler<TEventArgs>`. The first will give you a `delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e` to be used with empty EventArgs. The latter gives you the same but with your custom `TEventArgs` as second parameter.